# Filter date in python dataframe where column date equals yesterday

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I have this code to format a date column in my data and now I need to filter the resulting dataframe where this date column = yesterday's date whatever yesterday's date is.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", errors = 'coerce')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
merged_left['ResponseData releaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_left['ResponseData releaseDate'])
```

This is an example of one of the dates in the Date column before the 2 above lines of code are run:
`2023-07-26T23:27:14.895Z`

dtypes after the run for the Date column is datetime64[ns]

Any assistance would be appreciated

I have tried datetime.now()
I have tried datetime.datetime.now(tz) - timedelta(days=1)

Comment: `out = df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.normalize().eq(pd.Timestamp("today") - pd.DateOffset(days=1))]`

Comment: @mozway I think normalize does not remove the tz, so using UTC in getting yesterdays date is critical (`pd.Timestamp("today", tz="UTC") != pd.Timestamp("today")`)

Comment: @FObersteiner good point, I hadn't paid attention to the timezone, you have a good answer;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comapre `dates`, strings `YYYY-MM-DD` or `datetimes` by [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", errors = 'coerce')

yesterday = pd.Timestamp("today") - pd.Timedelta(1, "D")
out = df[df['Date'].dt.date.eq(yesterday.date())]
print (out)

out = df[df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').eq(yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]
print (out)

out = df[df['Date'].dt.normalize().eq(yesterday.normalize())]
print (out)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that avoids conversion to string: floor to the date and use UTC in yesterday's date since your input also specifies UTC. EX:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2023-07-26T23:27:14.895Z",
                            "2023-08-10T23:27:14.895Z",
                            "2023-08-12T23:27:14.895Z"],
                   "Num": [0,1,2]})

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

yesterday = pd.Timestamp("today", tz="UTC") - pd.DateOffset(1, "D")
print(yesterday)
# 2023-08-10 00:00:00+00:00

df_yesterday = df[df["Date"].dt.floor("D") == yesterday]
print(df_yesterday)
#                               Date  Num
# 1 2023-08-10 23:27:14.895000+00:00    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works for you:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data_series = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2023-08-11', '2023-08-10', '2023-08-12'])).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(data_series[data_series == yesterday])
```

Comment: pasted by mistake. Already edited